# Node.JS Server SYN flood DoS attack vulnerability?

Tags: node.js, security, ubuntu, lamp

I have had two VPS Ubuntu servers compromised by SYN flood DoS attacks.

The server environment is a Node.js server running on port: 3000, which I start using pm2 daemon as root user.

I also have LAMP (Apache web server, PHP, MySQL and phpMyAdmin) running on the same VPS (on the default port: 80) MySQL and phpMyAdmin which are all secured.

My question, is it safe to run my node server script on port: 3000 via pm2 as the root user? I have read on multiple websites its safe unless its running on port: 80. - Obviously the node server scripts are not accessible by the web server folder (sits outside).

I have also read its unsafe to run "`node server.js`" while logged in as the root user. It would be safer to setup a "safe user" (that asks for the password). [> source(1)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps) or do this [> source(2)](http://syskall.com/dont-run-node-dot-js-as-root/).

Anyone have any tips how to lockdown Node.js?

Comment: It is safest to NOT run your node server as root.  Then, nothing the server does will expose things only available as root. I have my server running on 8081 as a regular user (not as root) and I port forward port 80 to 8081 so all web traffic from the outside appears to be on port 80, but I don't have to run as root in order to serve port 80.  This requires you to write your server so it does not need root privileges (a generally good thing to do anyway).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks! so your server is not accessible from the outside from port: 8081? i don't need the node server running through port:80 - i am only using it with socket.io so i can connect to any port number. also are you using a regular user to run pm2 and your node server?

Comment: I'm using a regular user to run forever that runs my node server.  If you can run your server on a high port number, then you don't need the port forwarding - I just needed that to be able to run on port 80.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks allot for confirming that!! will try running as a regular user hopefully that will sort these attacks out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My NodeJS server is still getting hacked!! after locking down the `pm2` user by using a `"safe user"` by not running `node` as `root` user.

So I started looking around for other ways these pest's are getting in. I came across authentication methods for Node Client/Server communication. Here's a easy way to query the server with a unique key/code. If the server does not receive the correct key/code in the query parameter it refuses the connection of the client.

**Client Side:**

```
var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", { query: "foo=bar" });
```

**Server Side:**

```
io.use(function(socket, next){
    console.log("Query: ", socket.handshake.query);
    if (socket.handshake.query.foo == "bar") {
        return next();
    }
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

So far so good.. will report back if it doesn't work.